# Camel / MongoDB - $in operator with reference to another collection/document array

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I came across [this blog post](http://seanhess.github.io/2012/02/01/mongodb_relational.html) in looking for a way to organize relationships. What I'm getting confused on is the syntax behind the following statement. I realize by virtue of the javascript variables, the following is possible..

```
var party = { 
  _id: "chessparty", 
  name: "Chess Party!",
  attendees: ["seanhess", "bob"] 
}

var user = { _id: "seanhess", name: "Sean Hess", events: ["chessparty"]}

db.events.save(party)
db.users.save(user)

db.events.find({_id: {$in: user.events}}) // events for user
db.users.find({_id: {$in: party.attendees}}) // users for event
```

What is throwing me for a spin in the last two lines though, since what I'm trying to do is something like this in Java. So I understand the idea, but I want to accomplish this in Java, more specifically, the Camel/MongoDB component.

I've been referencing [the following documentation](http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html) and looking at the "findAll" operation. So would I need to first run a query to get the array, for example the "user.events" and then run a second query to find the list of events? Or is there a way to reference the field "events" in collection "db.user" as part of the query on "db.events"?

Something to the tune of the following with a single query..

```
pseudo idea: db.events.find({_id: {$in: [db.user.events]}})
```

Ultimately I'm looking to translate this into something like the following..

```
from("direct:findAll")
    .setBody().constant("{ \"_id\": {$in :\"user.events\" }}")
    .to("mongodb:myDb?database=sample&collection=events&operation=findAll")
    .to("mock:resultFindAll");
```

I'm a bit new to the mongodb camel component, so I'm wondering if there are any gurus that have already been there done that sort of thing?? And have any advice on the subject. Or to find out without 2 days of trial and error that this simple isn't possible..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd wrap this question up, it has been some time now and a few weeks ago I was able to work past this.

Basically I would up storing an array of userId's in the events collection..

example:

```
{
    _id : 22bjh2345j2k3v235,
    eventName : "something",
    eventDate : ISODate(...),
    attendees : [
        "abc123",
        "def098",
        "etc..."
    ]
}
```

essentially assigning users to events. This way I could find all events a user was participating in, and I wound up with a list of users per event.

if I wanted to find all events for a user:

```
from("direct:findAll")
.setBody().simple("{ \"attendees\": \"${header.userId}\" }")
.to("mongodb:myDb?database=sample&collection=events&operation=findAll")
.to("mock:resultFindAll");
```

Comment: what is the outputtype you have given?

Comment: Getting Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [java.lang.String] for value and when i use above code